# Should we include/stimulate IMDB links in our tag wikis/questions?

Tags: discussion

Most tags and questions on our site only contain titles of movies/series, without IMDB links. Wouldn't it be more useful for visitors to have an IMDB link to visit? In my opinion, it would enrich the look and feel of our site and add some more clarity to questions (especially with for remakes and older movies).

(Please note that I am not trying to promote IMDB but we might as well use their extensive database)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't sound like a bad idea to me.  Tag wikis are meant to be edited by the community.  If you think it would be helpful then feel free to add them.

Answer (score 2):

In and of itself an IMDB link is just a link, WP is typically better if an article exists.  However, if the link could be parsed by the server and the metadata could be integrated into the tag description, that would be a really valuable addition.  I think something like this is probably what the OP had in mind.  For instance, if you could see poster/release year/summary when you hover on a particular film's tag, it could enhance the site usability considerably.  There are torrent sites that have deployed a similar feature with great success.

Answer (score 1):

Standardizing the links to IMDB via some automation during question construction would be difficult to administer. Most readers on this site will supply IMDB links to questions they are interested in or supply them as part of their answers.

Comment: True, some answers include links to IMDB if the answer is somehow related to the info there (e.g. movie identification). However, I'm missing this in the tag wikis which should include a brief description on the subject for those interested in more. I think its particularly useful for film tags (e.g. Looper, Batman,...). I'm talking about the tag wikis, not the excerpts which are shown as a rollover as these are not clickable. If a user clicks on a tag and then clicks on "learn more", they should see the link.

Comment: @Origin - I have never been aware of "learn more" functionality from the tag wiki, and am not convinced I would ever use it. However, your usefulness for this should not be driven off by my skepticism. Feel free to add positive value, as the FAQ encourages. Sorry I rejected your tag wiki edits. Unless others have some fellings against, feel free to resubmit them.